# is the figure tag adequate for maps?

Tags: html, semantics

Is it semantically correct to use a `figure` element for a map (google maps for example)?

In my case it can me placed somewhere else without affecting the document flow. I would use the `figcaption` to store the address of the place shown on the map. But I'm still not sure if this suites to this usecase...

This is the w3c description:

> The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a
>   caption, that is self-contained and is typically referenced as a
>   single unit from the main flow of the document. The figure element can
>   be used to annotate illustrations, diagrams, photos, code listings,
>        etc., that are referenced in the main content of the document, but that could, without affecting the flow of the document, be moved
>   away from that primary content — e.g., to the side of the page, to
>   dedicated pages, or to an appendix.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-figure-element.html#the-figure-element

Comment: I would think so since it can be removed without affecting the content or removing important information if you have the address somewhere else in the main text of the page.

Comment: @Knyri thats also the definition of the article, thats why i am not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the W3C description the `<figure>` element is the perfect solution for a map. Especially if the map contains just an additional graphic info or clarification for what's on the page already.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it was a pretty good use of the figure element, provided that the map is not itself the primary content of the page.